# How to print the line that appears before found line

Tags: python, string

I am trying to print certain lines from a text file which is essentially like a web page source code. One particular text is repeated several times and I want to print the line that appears before it.

Example to explain it:

```
.
.
text1
text
.
.
text2
text
.
.
text3
text
.
.
```

Expected output:

```
text1
text2
text3
```

My code:

```
import re
hand = open('sample.txt')
for line in hand:
    line = line.rstrip()
    if re.search('text', line):
        print(line)
```

This code gives me the line `text` but I want the line above it.
I want to solve this using regex preferably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
hand = open('sample.txt')

prev_line = ''

for line in hand:
    line = line.rstrip()

    if 'text' in line:  # or if line == 'text'
        print(prev_line)

    prev_line = line
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by a few options:

To find all lines before the text line with *Positive Lookahead* of regex

```
print(re.findall("(?=text\S).*", hand))
```

Output

```
['text1', 'text2', 'text3']
```

*Or* to get the previous line that you find a match with regex and `enumerate`

```
for index, line in enumerate(hand):
    line = line.rstrip()
    if re.search('text\b', line):
        print(hand[index -1])
```

Output

```
text1
text2
text3
```